# What workarounds exist for DocumentDB "id" field restriction which requires string?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have a simple case where we want to take JSON documents directly from an API provider (Github) and store them in a DocumentDB Collection.  Unfortunately, the documents happen to have an "id" field which is numeric, and thus causes an error when trying to create the document.

This must be a common scenario, and I found a post which seems to indicate "the worst". However, I'm looking for confirmation.  I'm holding out a little hope that I don't have to write custom handling for the ID field, which modifies all documents upon every storage and retrieval operation just to make them compatible with DocumentDB.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/26386227-4aa2-48d5-9cc4-547caef18fb5/id-field-work-around-help-needed?forum=AzureDocumentDB

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "the worst" - DocumentDB `id` property is simply a string. And why would you need to modify your document on every retrieval and write? Seems like this is merely something you need to do when initially storing to docdb. Plus you can always add your own numeric id property if you so choose.

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in comments, I'm not exactly sure what the primary issue is, but DocumentDB's `id` property is a string. You'd need to convert your GitHub content's numeric id property to a string before saving in DocumentDB. Alternatively, you may create your own numeric property (other than `id`) to maintain the numeric data type, for future querying.

You cannot change the data type of `id` from string to numeric, within the collection itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback.  I think the suggestion in the article I provided is much more attractive than implementing the logic to mutating the type of any field which happens to be named "id" and happens to not be a string just for working with DocumentDB. I'm new to NoSQL in general, but I can see some other benefits for encapsulating documents on DocumentDB into outer objects based on their type name as well.  So, if I'm working with a repository, the JSON would be shaped like so:

```
{
  "repository": {
      "id": "Id from github",
      "foo": "bar"
  },
  "id" : "document-db-id"
}
```

Using this wrapping approach as a convention throughout my application makes sense to me.  I simply need to add a "type" parameter throughout my application for DocumentDB operations.

I can see some downsides as well. For example, it might require a layer between any Entity Frameworks for DocumentDB and SDKs which provide a data model for an API.

If anyone has any experience or advice about wrapping documents in "type" containers for NOSQL of any kind, it would be welcome.